# Assigning an argument to null verses nothing in the function

Tags: r, null, arguments

To my understanding, if I have functions like the one below:

```
hello1<- function(pillow){
       if (missing(pillow)){
      stop("You need to enter pillow")
    }
pillow
}
```

`hello1()` stops and returns the message that I want:

```
hello2<- function(pillow){
       if (is.null(pillow)){
      stop("You need to enter pillow")
    }
pillow
}
```

`hello2()` stops and returns the following message: 
`Error in hello2() : argument "pillow" is missing, with no default`

```
hello3<- function(pillow=NULL){
       if (is.null(pillow)){
      stop("You need to enter pillow")
    }
pillow
}
```

`hello3()` stops and returns the message that I want:

```
hello4<- function(pillow=NULL){
           if (missing(pillow)){
          stop("You need to enter pillow")
        }
    pillow
    }
```

`hello4()` stops and returns the message that I want:

To summarize, I can get the message that I want using `missing()` and `is.null()` when an argument is set to `NULL` but , when the argument is set to nothing, I can get the message that I want only with `missing()` but not with `is.null()`. That being said, I want to know what are pros and cons associated with assigning `NULL` in the argument verses not assigning `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big advantage of using `missing` is that you are explicit in what you are testing for (is the argument given or not?).  Default value `NULL` is less explicit since NULL can be a correct value for some functions.

A particular case is where the argument is computed by another function and in some corner cases it computes the value to be NULL.